# SymmetricDS can not register to server with Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, symmetricds

Hi I have Spring boot app with an embedded client and server. When the server is running and the client starts I see the following error.

```
    INFO  [client-001-job-3] o.j.s.s.impl.DataLoaderService - Using registration URL of http://localhost:8080/sync/server/registration?nodeGroupId=client&externalId=001&syncURL=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8081%2Fsync%2Fclient-001&schemaVersion=%3F&databaseType=H2&databaseVersion=1.4&symmetricVersion=3.11.9&deploymentType=client&hostName=.....

ERROR [client-001-job-3] o.j.s.s.impl.RegistrationService - Unexpected error during registration: Received an unexpected response code of 404 from the server
org.jumpmind.exception.HttpException: Received an unexpected response code of 404 from the server
```

My server.properties:

```
external.id=server
engine.name=server
sync.url=http://localhost:8080/sync/server
group.id=server
registration.url=
auto.registration=true
initial.load.create.first=true
auto.config.database=true
auto_reload=true
```

My client properties:

```
external.id=001
engine.name=client-001
sync.url=http://localhost:8081/sync/client-001
group.id=client
registration.url=http://localhost:8080/sync/server
initial.load.create.first=true
auto.config.database=true
auto.registration=true
auto_reload=true
```

### The sql what I run on the server:

### -- Node Groups

insert into sym_node_group (node_group_id) values ('client');

---

### -- Node Group Links

-- server sends changes to client when client pulls from server
insert into sym_node_group_link (source_node_group_id, target_node_group_id, data_event_action) values ('server', 'client', 'W');

-- client sends changes to server when client pushes to server
insert into sym_node_group_link (source_node_group_id, target_node_group_id, data_event_action) values ('client', 'server', 'P');

---

### -- Routers

insert into sym_router
(router_id,source_node_group_id,target_node_group_id,router_type,create_time,last_update_time)
values('server_2_client', 'server', 'client', 'default',current_timestamp, current_timestamp);

-- Default router sends all data from client to server
insert into sym_router
(router_id,source_node_group_id,target_node_group_id,router_type,create_time,last_update_time)
values('client_2_server', 'client', 'server', 'default',current_timestamp, current_timestamp);

Why can't the client register?
The server is running in  http://localhost:8080 
and the client  has http://localhost:8080/sync/server  for the registration.url

Comment: What’s the corresponding log on the server?

Comment: Nothing, so the 404 means that it can not reach the server.

Comment: This is the only info log:
INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed initialization in 14 ms

Comment: INFO  [client-001-job-3] o.j.s.s.impl.DataLoaderService - Using registration URL of http://localhost:8080/sync/server/registration?nodeGroupId=client&externalId=001&syncURL=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8081%2Fsync%2Fclient-001&schemaVersion=%3F&databaseType=H2&databaseVersion=1.4&symmetricVersion=3.11.9&deploymentType=client&hostName=XXXXXXX&ipAddress=XX3
ERROR [client-001-job-3] o.j.s.s.impl.RegistrationService - Unexpected error during registration: org.jumpmind.symmetric.transport.AuthenticationException
org.jumpmind.symmetric.transport.AuthenticationException: null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to register the endpoint to the Client as well.

```
  @Bean
  public ServletRegistrationBean<SymmetricServlet> symServlet() {
    ServletRegistrationBean<SymmetricServlet> bean = new ServletRegistrationBean<>(new SymmetricServlet(), "/sync/*");
    bean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    return bean;
  }
```